# What is the best way to store simple spatial data

Tags: database, spatial

I have a mind to build a simple game. It would have a playing board that is a 2D grid and players would be allowed to place tokens on the nodes in the grid.

Basically I could store tuples like this `{x, y, token}`

When rendering a UI that shows a part of the grid I expect to need spatial queries to gather the data. When scrolling I'd expect similar queries. Depending on the number of players the grid can become massive, but realistically I don't expect it to grow beyond what a relational database can comfortably handle.

I was looking into [Spatial Databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database), but I have no idea if that adds more problems than it solves. What is the way to go about this? Should I use a Spatial Database, and if so which one is best suited to this (simple) problem?

Comment: I have no experience with (geo)spatial databases, but they seem like a good fit from performance perspective. Specifically queries like `x BETWEEN a AND b AND y BETWEEN c AND d` are suppose to be very effective.

Comment: @Tomasz yeah, that's why I'm asking. There are plenty out there and I'd love some tips on where to start looking for this relatively simple problem.

Comment: I think you should keep it simple and use what you are familiar with until  (or *IF*) it proves insufficient.  Like Tomasz said, you can do simple range queries on an X & Y and that'll be just fine.

Comment: I've got a good experience with Spatial databases but, as the previous commenters said, you will not benefit much from it. Ranges queries will be very easy, distance calculations can be done with simple trigonometry (although using spatial databases is not that hard). Anyway, if you really want to go the spatial DB way, most DBs out there offer spatial support: Sql Server, PostGree, MySql, Oracle. Some are more mature than others, but for the kind of data you've described their capabilities should be similar.

Comment: I'm thinking to go with MongoDB, as I have plenty of comfort with that and their spatial features seem to go well beyond what I need.

Comment: Yeah, MongoDB is a really nice option and should suit your problem just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spacial indexing gives you tremendous benefits compared to traditional (1-dimensional) indexes. Queries like

```
x BETWEEN a AND b AND y BETWEEN c AND d
```

will just be able to use indexes either for `x` or `y`. This means the DBMS will be able to exclude records outside the a-b stripe (column), but for all the records inside it has to grind through the `y` values. (It does not matter if you have a compound index for `x` and `y` because x potentially has unlimited cardinality).

A spacial index can handle two dimensions simultaneously, so it will exclude most of the DB, it only has to test individual values in a few *grid* units which intersect with your interval.